# Firebase handleIntent not received actual extra param

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

`FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Intent intent)` bypassing `onMessageReceived()` completely.
The former is always called even for notification messages no matter if the app is in background or not.

But i can not get any extra param when i called from console.`firebase` -> Notification

Comment: Have you every library with same version ?

Comment: If you want to pass extra params , then use notification type 'Data'

Comment: Currently i am sending like this:
{
  "to": "eK2fimzgPko:APA91bGBwcxgXdq0O_Md0dIl9I64itHDs04yi0vrYwHwPv0u3IobgogYO55EjM9Ckzs0W3EhDSu_cjRtQCRrz1zRyJrmy_8acpaqeSlS9V9FvBzPjL5sp0S14S0HOBtxsBezfPJUdusQ",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Test message from REST",
    "body":"dsajlkgj asklghjas gklasdjklgn",
  }
}

Comment: need to change here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you you getting any notification from firebase or you having trouble parsing the data?
If you have manually configured firebase, please make sure you are adding **FirebaseMessagingService** in Manifest file so that your app can get incoming messages.and google.json file is updated and synchronized with your app in firebase console.

Comment: He share code and i can debug all the scenario but in that pushnotification comes in handleIntent method not in onMessageReceived method

Comment: Also i have tried to send from RestClient but everytime i get Error=MissingRegistration

Comment: @ashish check this link hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814193/firebase-fcm-push-getting

Comment: I have tried but not success. So i have to go with downgrade of firebase message dependency.

Comment: It seems the content-Type is not proper, copy from firebase docs the content-types

Comment: I have notice that point and improve while send notification from RestClient but same thing i am getting Error=MissingRegistration

Comment: Ok try clearing your app data and fetch a fresh fcm token and try sending it through rest client. And by the way are you getting the same errorlog while sent from console?. Whats happening when you send it through console