# Firebase cloud messaging authorizion error Error=MissingRegistration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

and when i try from http call but i am getting response from FCM :

> Error=MissingRegistration

[image]

```
 { "data":{
    "score":"5x1",
    "time":"15:10"
    }
    ,
    "to":"fcm_token"
    }
```

Comment: @nilesh : Can you please answer intend of edit the question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486192/gcm-error-missingregistration-sending-messages-via-json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814193/firebase-fcm-push-getting-error-missing-registration-android

Comment: @NileshRathod : Thank you for your answer. But i have tried as per your reference answer but i still getting this error.

Comment: Is the missing `}` a typo? Also, is the Server key left out intentionally?